Throwing ImmediateRequeueAmqpException in a handler causes ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler to log an error stacktrace
In my Spring Integration Flow, I am throwing an ImmediateRequeueAmqpException to get the message requeued for another instance to handle the message, but I get stacktraces logged by the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler. I would expect not to get an error logged and the message just rejected to RabbitMQ.
Is it correct to throw this, or should I be handling this differently? If correct, why is it logging stacktraces rather than just rejecting the message?
2024-07-26T10:42:32.283Z  WARN 1 --- [erContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1794) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1686) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1592) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1583) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListenerAndHandleException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1528) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.lambda$executeListener$8(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1082) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1018) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1420) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1322) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor@7eae55] (initiateSchedulerFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3)]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:329) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:501) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:356) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:285) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:249) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:151) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:329) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:501) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:356) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:285) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:249) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:151) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:329) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:501) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:356) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:285) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:249) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:151) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:329) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:302) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.lambda$sendMessage$1(MessageProducerSupport.java:262) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:262) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$200(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69) ~[spring-integration-amqp-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:397) ~[spring-integration-amqp-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:360) ~[spring-integration-amqp-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1682) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.ImmediateRequeueAmqpException: No slots available to process request
    at com.acme.scheduler.schedulerservice.flows.InitiateSchedulerFlow.registerSchedulerRequest(InitiateSchedulerFlow.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.acme.scheduler.schedulerservice.flows.InitiateSchedulerFlow.lambda$buildFlow$1(InitiateSchedulerFlow.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.invokeMethod(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:208) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:95) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:145) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    ... 90 common frames omitted



That is a default logic of the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler:
public void handleError(Throwable t) {
    log(t);

....

protected void log(Throwable t) {
    if (this.logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        this.logger.warn("Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.", t);
    }
}

And there is no way that the framework may make a decision about logging or not such an exception.
Since your expectation do not have it logged, then you can increase logging level for this ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler category to ERROR. Or you can extend this class and override its log() method respectively to skip such a warning for that specific ImmediateRequeueAmqpException in the stack trace.

I will give one of those a go. Can you confirm that the framework will see the ImmediateRequeueAmqpException and handle it appropriately by telling RabbitMQ to re-queue the message?

Don't worry about the last question, I just debugged and stepped through and I see that the org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.support.ContainerUtils class unwraps it and handles it correctly
